# Process & recommendations to obtain a prepaid micro-SIM card in Jakarta (Indonesia)?

Tags: cellphones, indonesia, jakarta

What are the requirements to obtain a pre-paid micro-SIM in Jakarta, Indonesia (passport, cost, etc)?

What are the recommendations for where to obtain a micro-SIM (7-11, cellular company store)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fortunately, Indonesia is not [India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/getting-a-sim-card-prepay-in-india).  Here's how to do it:

Walk outside your hotel, pick up a rock, throw it.  It will land on a shopping mall, convenience store, corner shop, *wartel* or guy squatting on the pavement festooned with colorful signs for [Indosat](http://www.indosat.com/) (IM3), [Telkomsel](http://www.telkomsel.com/) (simPATI) or [XL Axiata](http://www.xl.co.id/).  Hand over around Rp 10,000 ($1), preferably while showing them your phone and its SIM card slot to make sure they give you the right size.  Enjoy your shiny new microSIM!

Comment: You can also get a SIM at the airport (CGK) near the baggage claim.

Comment: Any difference of coverage between operators?

Comment: Telkomsel has the largest network (it's the national telco's mobile branch), Indosat comes in second, XL is a good third.  Any of them will be fine unless you're going *really* off the beaten track, in which case Telkomsel will likely be your best bet.