# International SIM Card: Travelling USA to India

Tags: air-travel, cellphones

I am planning to go India on coming Monday. I tried to google about international SIM card but got confused with their plans. It would be great if someone point me out best international SIM card. Some info is as below:

1. Travelling from USA (Sanjose) to India (Delhi).
2. I will stay for a month.
3. I have Google Nexus 4 unlocked GSM phone.

My basic need is that I can have such card using that I can call to any India number during my journey and when my flight land at Delhi, at least I can inform to my relatives.

Pleass suggest me such SIM card. Also, let me know which I can directly buy from store rather than online purchase as I have just 4 days in USA (flying on Monday, 17 Feb 2014.).

Comment: To clarify, do you want to get a special travelling/roaming sim that'll work anywhere in the world but at a premium everywhere, or are you looking to get an Indian sim card?

Comment: Thank you Gagravarr for the response. An indian SIM card would be great. I dont have to worry about my international call.

Comment: This should answer your question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/getting-a-sim-card-prepay-in-india

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is no such thing as an international SIM card. They are always registered in a country and just the roaming fees are somewhat cheaper than the average mobile phone provider's ones.

If you only go to India than you should definitely get an Indian prepaid SIM card.

I do this in any country that I stay more than 2-3 days in and it has proven to be the best solution.

I have not been to India, but I don't see why it would be different there.

In most countries, SIM cards cost anything between $0.30 and $5. They often come with credit already. Local phone calls and txt are usually extremely cheap and you can buy an for a few bucks internet package as well. I never paid more than $10 to $20 for a month of lightly phone + txt and heavy data usage.

As soon as you are there, just head to the first mobile phone shop you see and explain to them what you want. Might be a good idea to do this in the airport already, as chances to find someone who speaks proper English are higher and this makes negotiating technical details much easier. Also airport shops don't tend to rip tourists off too much.

You might need to show your passport, so they can register the number for you.

Comment: It's indeed basically the same in India, but getting your hands on that prepaid SIM can be considerably more difficult than most countries.  See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/getting-a-sim-card-prepay-in-india for the full scoop.