# Travelling to India question regarding sim card

Tags: india, cellphones

Hi all I am planning to travel to jalandhar India for 2 weeks in December and I need to be able to use my phone almost as soon as I land.

I read a few of the other posts saying that there are booths in the Amritsar airport where I can buy a local prepaid minutes+data sim by providing some passport photos. However these posts were back from 2011-2013 and I was wondering has anything changed since? Is the time it takes to activate the same? The posts said anywhere between 15minutes and 2 hours, is that still the case?

Also if anything else has changed since please let me know

Comment: One of the other posts: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/getting-a-sim-card-prepay-in-india

Answer (score 3):

Nothing has changed to indicate the time to activate would have changed. In addition to the photographs, you will be required to provide proof of your address in India. I would also be prepared to give copies of passport, visa and a proof of residence in my home country.

In case you need a phone as soon as you land, I would suggest using a payphone at the airport.

Comment: Great thanks, 1-2 hours is still the norm before the sim is activated and I can use my phone?